# Populate rows based on matching data

Tags: excel

Im working on an excel spreadsheet that has multiple columns.

My goal is to populate column C with another columns data based on matching figures. I need to check two columns for matching data in two other columns.

I know that I can accomplish this in part using =VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE) but that only works if Im matching data from one cell against two other cells.

I need to match two cells against two other cells then populate the new column with column F's data

Column F should populate Column C

My spread sheet looks something like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 1 |  | name 1 | 1 | 111 |
| name 2 | 2 |  | name 2 | 2 | 222 |
| name 3 | 3 |  | name 2 | 3 | 333 |
| name 10 | 4 |  | name 6 | 4 | 444 |

ect.

So if the column name in bith A and integer in B match the column name and int in both D and E, populate column C with column Fs integer

column C should populate with column F's data but I need to check column A and B against column D and E.

if I use `=VLOOKUP(A2:B2,D:E:F,2,FALSE)`, Im met with a value error.
`=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1,(A:A=D:D)*(B:B=E:E),0))` also met me with an error.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you have access to `XLOOKUP()` formula then it would be best fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected formula:

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1,(A1=D:D)*(B1=E:E),0))
```

Enter it as array formula - using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

[image]